# Can you take 10 on Aid Another?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

I've only seen the "take 10" specifically disabled for ritual checks (PH1, p. 300).
Are they allowed for Aid Another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Technically yes, in practice usually no**

From the RC, p127:

> **Taking 10:** When creatures are not in a rush or not involved in an encounter or a skill challenge, they can choose to take 10 on a skill check. ...

Nothing in that list forbids you from taking 10 when you aid another. It *does*, however, ban taking 10 in most of the situations in which you would actually want to use the aid another action, skill challenges in particular.

Technically, you can use aid another to provide an ally a bonus on an attack roll.  This is almost always a bad idea.  If you were to do this, however, you could not take 10 because attack rolls are not skill checks and you can only take 10 on skill checks, in addition to generally being rushed and threatened in situations wherein you are making attack rolls.

Comment: But your cited text says "when creatures are not ... involved in an encounter"!
Unless i'm missing something, generally Aid another is done in combat in order to get the +2 to hit, right?

Comment: @Squera it can be used as such (though it's not exactly a good action economy item). It's more proper use is in a skill challenge or skill check attempt in order to allow other characters to get involved.

Comment: @Squera Taking 10 is limited to when `not involved in an encounter`, but Aid Another is not. So you can take 10 on Aid Another, but not during an encounter or a skill challenge, or when rushed. Which is most of the times you'd use it.